# Best way to duplicate parent and associated child records in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ActiveRecord: How can I clone nested associations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711956/activerecord-how-can-i-clone-nested-associations)

I have a table with `invoices` which in turn can have many `items`.

Now in my `invoices` index view I would like to place a link next to each `invoice` saying *Duplicate Invoice*.

Without the child records this would be quite easy:

```
<%= link_to "Duplicate", new_invoice_path(invoice.attributes) %>
```

But how can this be done if the invoice's `items` should be duplicated as well?

As a Rails newbie I can't get my head around this. Can all this be handled by the `new` action inside my controller?

```
def new
  @invoice = current_user.invoices.build(:project_id => params[:project_id])
  @title = "New invoice"
end
```

Or do I need to create another function named e.g. `copy` inside my controller?

What is the best practice?

Thanks for any input...

Comment: https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable

Answer (score 8):

The logic should go in the model

in `invoice.rb`:

```
def deep_dup
  new_invoice = Invoice.create(self.dup.attributes)
  items.each do |item|
    new_invoice.items.create(item.dup.attributes)
  end
  return new_invoice
end
```

Then in the controller, make an action called `duplicate`:

```
def duplicate
  new_invoice = @invoice.deep_dup
  redirect to new_invoice
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this in your create action:

```
def create
  @invoice = Invoice.new(params[:invoice]
   #find duplicate invoice (if exists)
   duplicate_invoice = Invoice.find(params[:duplicate_invoice_id])
   unless duplicate_invoice.nil?
     items = nil
     duplicate_items = duplicate_invoice.items
     duplicate_items.each do |child|
       item = Item.new(child.attributes)
       item.save
       items << item
     end  
   end
   if @invoice.save
     @invoice.items << items #add the duplicate items to the duplicate invoice
     #handle your redirects....
   end
end
```

Essentially what you can do pass the id of the duplicate invoice to your create action, find the invoice that you intent to duplicate and then process it's children items into an array of duplicate items. The final step is to add those newly duplicated items to your newly duplicated invoice. This is obviously untested and it's going to require a little additional work on your end but I hope you get the gist of the idea. There's probably other ways to accomplish this.

Of course, there are also gems that can do this for you but it's your call.