# Duplicate/clone a record and it's associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Game
  has_many :players, dependent: :destroy
end

class Player
  belongs_to :game
end
```

Let's say we have one game and three players associated to it.

**How do we duplicate these four records in the most succinct way, without any use of gems?**

[Here are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201522/best-way-to-duplicate-parent-and-associated-child-records-in-ruby-on-rails) [two questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711956/activerecord-how-can-i-clone-nested-associations) on SO around the same subject, but are either utilizing gems or seem overly complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code can be a start:

```
class Game
  has_many :players

  def clone
    attributes = self.attributes
    ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'].each do |ignored_attribute|
      attributes.delete(ignored_attribute)
    end
    clone = Game.create(attributes)
    self.players.each do |player|
      player.clone.update_attributes(game_id: clone.id)
    end

    clone
  end
end

class Player
  belongs_to :game

  def clone
    attributes = self.attributes
    ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'].each do |ignored_attribute|
      attributes.delete(ignored_attribute)
    end
    clone = Player.create(attributes)

    clone
  end
end
```

with this, you could create a module `acts_as_clonable`, and include it in your models, with some options:

```
class Game
  has_many :players

  acts_as_clonable relations: [:players], destroy_original: false, ignored_attributes: [:this_particular_attribute]
```

If you have the ambition, you could make a Gem with this... ;-)

Comment: You're welcome, fellow stranger! Ahah your username fits perfectly in this situation!