# amoeba not cloning all :has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amoeba-gem

I am using the Amoeba gem to clone a model and all children. The gem is working well with one exception - there is one :has_many association that is not being picked up.

My parent Model is Option:

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :products, as: :productable, dependent: :destroy
has_many :censusinfos, :autosave => true

belongs_to :rating

accepts_nested_attributes_for :censusinfos


amoeba do
  enable
end

# other code.....
```

Products is being cloned appropriately, but the issue is on :censusinfos. That model is defined as:

```
class Censusinfo < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :census_sheets
has_many :census_fields
belongs_to :option

#other code......
```

CensusField children are copied correctly, but CensusSheet is not being cloned.

Any thoughts/ideas why??

Thanks!

Greg

Comment: Should't you enable `recursive copying of associations` by including in `class Censusinfo` `  amoeba do  enable  end` . I think you found amoeba hear right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711956/activerecord-how-can-i-clone-nested-associations

Comment: You were correct! Did not "enable" amoeba in the Censusinfo association.

Comment: @Gpnect76 Thanks a lot. I posted an answer to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the documentation at the following link

[ActiveRecord: How can I clone nested associations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711956/activerecord-how-can-i-clone-nested-associations)

Should't you enable recursive copying of associations by including in class Censusinfo `amoeba do enable end`?

```
class Censusinfo < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :census_sheets
has_many :census_fields
belongs_to :option

amoeba do
  enable
end
```

Thanks

Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add "enable" to Censusinfo. Example below. Thanks to Fabrizio!

```
class Censusinfo < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :census_sheets
has_many :census_fields
belongs_to :option

amoeba do
  enable
end

#other code......
```